# How to use Javassist in an Android project?

Tags: android, javassist

I was trying to use Javassist in my Android project, but it didn't work. Whenever I got a CtClass from the default ClassPool, a NotFoundException was thrown. I mean the Javassist is included successfully and code is OK but when I run my program  and trying to get a CtClass using the code below a NotFoundException was thrown.

```
ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
pool.importPackage("com.nd.android");
try {
    CtClass ctClass = pool.get("com.nd.android.aoptest.Test");
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    //NotFoundException always thrown
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I was told that Javassist can only used in a Java project, is there any other version for Android? Or can anyone tell me how to deal with this problem ?

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nd.android.aoptest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA'
}
```

Comment: Use webview instead

Comment: Have you included the jar in your project?

Comment: Android Studio , by gradle , dependencies {
      compile 'org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA'
}·

Answer (score 4):

Javassist operates on Java byte code while Android runs its cutom Dalvik byte code format. You can therefore not use Javassist on Android.

Instead, you can use a subset of Byte Buddy with Byte Buddy Android or use dexmaker.